# How to make OpenGL viewport have the exact size and position of my QML item which renders into it?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

I'm trying to render a `640x360` red square inside a `1280x720` window. The problem is that OpenGL's viewport won't automatically be inside the area occupied by the square into the Qt window system. That is, if my video object have `640x360` dimensions, the OpenGl viewport still have the `1280x720` dimensions (WHY?).

Anyways, I can fix that by using `glViewport(this->x, this->y, this->width, this->height);`. The problem is that in OpenGL, the coordinate system has origin at the left low corner, and `this->x, this->y, this->width, this->height` are from the object's coordinates in QML syntax, where the origin is in the upper left corner. The result is this:

**main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import OpenGlVideoQtQuick2 1.0


Grid {
    columns: 2
    spacing: 2    
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    OpenGlVideoQtQuick2 {
        width: 640
        height: 360
    }

}
```

**but the red square occupies the 3rd grid instead of the 1st one:**

[image]

I could **easily** fix that by doing `glViewport(this->x, WINDOW_HEIGHT-this->y, this->width, this->height);` where `WINDOW_HEIGHT` would have the value `720`, however I don't think I should trust the OpenGL viewport to always have the size of the window, so instead I should get the OpenGl viewport dimensions, but I don't think that that is possible.

I tried

```
GLint dims[2] = {9999, 9999};
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS, dims);
std::cout << "dimenson x:" << dims[0] << " dimenson y:" << dims[1] << std::endl;
```

which gives me `dimenson x:8192 dimenson y:8192` which makes no sense to me.

Here is the OpenGL rendering code: https://github.com/lucaszanella/QQuickPaintedItemBug/blob/0a8ef6b5229afa7113ec1e4e3838981042792329/OpenGlVideoQtQuick2.cpp

You can view an entire buildable project here: https://github.com/lucaszanella/QQuickPaintedItemBug/tree/0a8ef6b5229afa7113ec1e4e3838981042792329

Comment: Did yout take a look at Qt example? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html

Comment: @BenjaminT as I understood, this example will always put the viewport in coordiates (0,0) and will have the size of the window*aspec ratio, which is not what I need. I need it to have the size and position of my QML item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is the solution in pseudo code:

```
int w = item->width() * window->devicePixelRatio();
int h = item->height() * window->devicePixelRatio();
int x = item->x();
int y = window->height()* window->devicePixelRatio() - h - item->y()

glViewport(x, y, w, h);
```

I have tested with Qt ***Scene Graph - OpenGL Under QML*** example.
Here are the changes I made:

**main.qml**

```
Squircle {
    x: 80
    y: 120
    width: 160
    height: 240
    [...]
}
```

**squircle.cpp**

```
void Squircle::sync()
{
    if (!m_renderer) {
        m_renderer = new SquircleRenderer();
        connect(window(), &QQuickWindow::beforeRendering, m_renderer, &SquircleRenderer::paint, Qt::DirectConnection);
    }
    m_renderer->setViewportSize(this->size().toSize() * window()->devicePixelRatio());
    m_renderer->setPosition(this->position().toPoint());
    m_renderer->setT(m_t);
    m_renderer->setWindow(window());
}

void SquircleRenderer::paint()
{
    [...]
    int y = (m_window->size()* m_window->devicePixelRatio()).height() - m_viewportSize.height() -  m_position.y();
    glViewport(m_position.x(), y, m_viewportSize.width(), m_viewportSize.height());
    [...]
}
```

**squircle.h**

```
class SquircleRenderer : public QObject, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    void setPosition(const QPoint &position) { m_position = position; }

    [...]

private:
    [...]
    QPoint m_position;
};
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it kinda works. But did you notice that the rest of the window is still black? It's like the OpenGL were still working on that area. Do you know how to remove it?

Comment: @LucasZanella It is black, because there is nothing there. What would you want it to look like ?

Comment: but it hides the color of the background

Comment: @LucasZanella It does not. Your OpenGL code is rendered before any rendering is done by Qt. So in fact if you did have an explicit background in your app (e.g. by replacing the Grid by a Rectangle), the background would be rendered on top of your OpenGL code and hide it. What can make you feel that the background is hidden is the call `win->setClearBeforeRendering(false)`. This call will prevent Qt from rendering the default background of the window, but without it, the window background would be rendered ontop of your OpenGL.

Comment: @LucasZanella I do not think you can improve much with the current design you have. An alternative would be to use `QSGSimpleMaterialShader` or `QSGMaterialShader` with a `QSGGeometryNode`. There is an example on how to use it: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-simplematerial-example.html

If you go this way, your shader should render inside of the QML item tree like any normal item. Which is not possible with your current design.

Comment: I'm intersted in this way you pointed, however I do not know how to use OpenGL functions inside this Shader class. Do you have any material on this or can give any kind of help?

Comment: @LucasZanella Sadly, no. I never used it, so I have nothing beside Qt documentation.

Comment: @LucasZanella You might also be interested by the QQuickFramebufferObject: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/05/11/integrating-custom-opengl-rendering-with-qt-quick-via-qquickframebufferobject/

Comment: I already have a working QQuickFrameBufferObject implementation which renders video inside the QML item as you pointed. However I had to change it for this way I'm doing rigth now because I need my renderable QML item to inherit from QQuickItem directly, not inheriting from something that inherits from QQuickItem, because of this diamong problem I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210837/solving-this-specific-c-diamond-problem-for-qt-classes

Comment: So the `QSGSimpleMaterialShader` way you mentioned would work, because the QML item inherits from QQuickItem directly. Sadly, it's too much different from what I have and I'll need some help. If you get to know about how to render using `QSGSimpleMaterialShader`, please contact me, and thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Here is the `QQuickFrameBufferObject` video renderer in case you need someday https://github.com/lucaszanella/orwell/blob/5d05892a9fe25ad1b17ff9d88ef566618e93ef4d/OpenGlBufferQtQuick.cpp

Comment: @LucasZanella Did you try to compose your React item with the Framebuffer item. The Framebuffer is only useful for the rendering, it's an implementation detail. So you can make it as a child of the React item (or of the subclass).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make a subclass because of the diamond problem I mentioned. What you mean by composition? You mean simply putting Framebuffer inside a QML item? I can see this kinda working if I make Framebuffer's width and height to follow the parent's one, but I don't think much things would work, like internal margin and bottoms. Is this what you said or I interpreted wrongly?

Comment: @LucasZanella Exactly, just putting one inside the other. Indeed you will need to add some code so that the Framebuffer Object follows the geometry of the Reactitem, but this is doable, that's exactly what you do with anchoring in QML, except you do it explicitly in C++

Comment: I implemented a video renderer using `QSGSimpleMaterialShader` as you said. Only one simple thing is missing, can you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842937/rendering-video-in-qt-opengl-using-updatepaintnode-new-frame-only-appears-when