# Rendering video in QT/OpenGL using updatePaintNode: new frame only appears when I resize screen

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, video, h.264

I'm writing an OpenGL video renderer in Qt and it's almost working. It'll only render the video if I resize the window. So every time I resize the window, a new frame is drawn on the screen. I think I'm forgetting to call some function after updating the frame.

Here's the first frame, when there's no video data:
[image]

After I resize the screen, a frame is drawn:
[image]

```
#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>
#include <qguiapplication.h>
#include <qsgmaterial.h>
#include <qsgnode.h>
#include <qquickitem.h>
#include <qquickview.h>
#include <qsgsimplerectnode.h>
#include <qsgsimplematerial.h>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include "OpenGlMaterialQQuickItem.h"
#include <iostream>

#define GET_STR(x) #x
#define VERTEX_ATTRIBUTE 3

struct State
{
    public:
        int frameWidth = 1920;
        int frameHeight = 1080;
        unsigned char *datas[3] = {0};

    private:
        bool firstRender = true;

    public:
        void updateData(unsigned char**data, int frameWidth, int frameHeight)
        {
            this->frameWidth = frameWidth;
            this->frameHeight = frameHeight;

            if (firstRender) {
                datas[0] = new unsigned char[frameWidth*frameHeight];  //Y
                datas[1] = new unsigned char[frameWidth*frameHeight/4];//U
                datas[2] = new unsigned char[frameWidth*frameHeight/4];//V
                firstRender = false;
            }

            memcpy(datas[0], data[0], frameWidth*frameHeight);
            memcpy(datas[1], data[1], frameWidth*frameHeight/4);
            memcpy(datas[2], data[2], frameWidth*frameHeight/4);
};

class Shader : public QSGSimpleMaterialShader<State>
{
    QSG_DECLARE_SIMPLE_SHADER(Shader, State);
    private:
        QOpenGLFunctions *glFuncs = nullptr;
        GLuint unis[3] = {0};
        GLuint texs[3] = {0};
        QSize m_viewportSize;
        bool firstRender = true;
    public:
        const char *vertexShader() const override {
            return GET_STR(
                        uniform highp mat4 qt_Matrix;
                        attribute vec4 vertexIn;
                        attribute vec2 textureIn;
                        varying vec2 textureOut;
                        void main(void)
                        {
                            gl_Position = qt_Matrix * vertexIn;
                            textureOut = textureIn;
                        }
                );
        }

        const char *fragmentShader() const override {
            return GET_STR(
                        varying vec2 textureOut;
                        uniform sampler2D tex_y;
                        uniform sampler2D tex_u;
                        uniform sampler2D tex_v;
                        uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
                        void main(void)
                        {
                            vec3 yuv;
                            vec3 rgb;
                            yuv.x = texture2D(tex_y, textureOut).r;
                            yuv.y = texture2D(tex_u, textureOut).r - 0.5;
                            yuv.z = texture2D(tex_v, textureOut).r - 0.5;
                            rgb = mat3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                                0.0, -0.39465, 2.03211,
                                1.13983, -0.58060, 0.0) * yuv;
                            gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0) * qt_Opacity;
                        }
                    );
        }

        QList<QByteArray> attributes() const override
        {
            return {QByteArrayLiteral("vertexIn"), QByteArrayLiteral("textureIn")};
        }

        void initialize()
        {
            if (!program()->isLinked()) {
                return;
            }

            QSGSimpleMaterialShader<State>::initialize();
            glFuncs = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
            program()->bind();

            glFuncs->glGenTextures(3, texs);
        }

        void updateState(const State *state, const State *) override
        {
            //Y
            glFuncs->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
            glFuncs->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glFuncs->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glFuncs->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, state->frameWidth, state->frameHeight, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

            //U
            glFuncs->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]);
            glFuncs->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glFuncs->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glFuncs->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, state->frameWidth/2, state->frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

            //V
            glFuncs->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
            glFuncs->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glFuncs->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glFuncs->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, state->frameWidth / 2, state->frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

            glFuncs->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glFuncs->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
            glFuncs->glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, state->frameWidth, state->frameHeight, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, state->datas[0]);
            glFuncs->glUniform1i(unis[0], 0);

            glFuncs->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+1);
            glFuncs->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]); 
            glFuncs->glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, state->frameWidth/2, state->frameHeight / 2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, state->datas[1]);
            glFuncs->glUniform1i(unis[1],1);

            glFuncs->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+2);
            glFuncs->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
            glFuncs->glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, state->frameWidth / 2, state->frameHeight / 2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, state->datas[2]);
            glFuncs->glUniform1i(unis[2], 2);

            glFuncs->glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
        }

        void resolveUniforms() override
        {
            unis[0] = program()->uniformLocation("tex_y");
            unis[1] = program()->uniformLocation("tex_u");
            unis[2] = program()->uniformLocation("tex_v");
        }
};

class Node: public QSGGeometryNode, public FrameUpdater
{
    public:
        State state;
        //QQuickItem* item;
        Node()
        {
            material = Shader::createMaterial();
            setMaterial(material);
            setFlag(OwnsMaterial, true);

            QSGGeometry *g = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_TexturedPoint2D(), 4);
            QSGGeometry::updateTexturedRectGeometry(g, QRect(), QRect());
            setGeometry(g);
            setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsGeometry, true);

            stream = new MediaStream("rtsp://admin:19929394@192.168.1.178:10554/tcp/av0_0");
            stream->setFrameUpdater((FrameUpdater *) this);
            boost::thread mediaThread(&MediaStream::run, stream);
        }

        void updateData(unsigned char**data, int frameWidth, int frameHeight)
        {
            material->state()->updateData(data, frameWidth, frameHeight);
            markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyMaterial);
            //item->update();
        }

    private:
        QSGSimpleMaterial<State> *material;
        MediaStream* stream;

};

QSGNode * OpenGlMaterialQQuickItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *node, UpdatePaintNodeData *) //override
{
    std::cout << "updatePaintNode called " << std::endl;
    Node *n = static_cast<Node *>(node);
    if (!node)
        n = new Node();
    //n->item = this;
    QSGGeometry::updateTexturedRectGeometry(n->geometry(), boundingRect(), QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1));


    n->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyGeometry | QSGNode::DirtyMaterial);
    return n;
}
```

To understand how the code updates a video frame: `boost::thread mediaThread(&MediaStream::run, stream);` creates a thread that will insert video data through `void Node::updateData(unsigned char**data, int frameWidth, int frameHeight)`. This data is written inside the `State` struct.

**The only thing that is missing is a way to tell Qt that it needs to draw another frame. What is missing?**

PS: this is the `QQuickItem`:

```
class OpenGlMaterialQQuickItem: public ReactItem
{
    //Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString uri WRITE setUri)// NOTIFY uriChanged)

    public:
        std::string uri;

        QSGNode *updatePaintNode(QSGNode *node, UpdatePaintNodeData *) override;

        OpenGlMaterialQQuickItem()
        {
            setFlag(ItemHasContents, true);
        }

        void setUri(const QString &a) {
            uri = a.toStdString();
        }

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Qt documentation this is done by calling `QQuickItem::update()`.
Note that you must set the flag `QQuickItem::ItemHasContents` on the item first.

#### Update from comments

When you uncomment `item->update();` you get `QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread`, because of 2 things:

1. The `QQuickItem::update()` forwards the request to the window and then to the platform adaptation. In some (all ?) cases, the implementation uses a QTimer to schedule the repaint.
2. You call `item->update();` not from the GUI thread. Likely you call it directly from the boost thread you use to read the video.

So in the end, `item->update();` fails to start the timer, and nothing happens.

A solution can be to make sure you call `QQuickItem::update()` from the GUI thread.

Maybe this should work:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(item, &QQuickItem::update, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

This should call `QQuickItem::update()` from `item->thread()`.

Comment: Look at the commented line `item->update()`. It's there because I tried to update QQuickItem before, but it didn't work and I also got this warning: `QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread`

Comment: ps: I updated the quetion with my `QQuickItem` code

Comment: @LucasZanella I have edited my answer. If you are using Qt < 5.10 you need to replace `&QQuickItem::update` with `"update"`.